# Firebase Cloud Functions and Cloud Firestore Regions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

when adding a new Firebase application I'm presented with the following warning if the europe-west3 Cloud Firestore location is selected - about billing and latency if Cloud Functions are to be used

[image]

does this mean that we should not be using Firestore if we need to store our data in the EU and plan to use Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 1):

Current state (**04/2020**):

- *Google Cloud Functions* are available in europe-west3 (Frankfurt) with [Tier2-pricing](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations) but is available for Tier1 in europe-west1 (Belgium) and europe-west2 (London)
- *Google Firebase Firestore* can be [used](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations) in europe-west2 (London), europe-west3 (Frankfurt) and europe-west6 (Zürich)
- *Google Cloud Firestore* in [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/locations) and [Native](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/locations) mode can be used in europe-west2 (London), europe-west3 (Frankfurt) and europe-west6 (Zürich) but also in multi-region mode (europe-west1 (Belgium), europe-west4 (Eemshaven)) which is more expensive.

Therfore there are now intersections you can use to use *Google Cloud Functions* and *Google Firebase Firestore* in the same region. If you want to have free egress costs can use **europe-west2**.

If you don't use it in the same region you can still use it together but there are trans-region egress costs you have to keep in mind. As the warning states you also have to keep latency in mind. The latency issue depends on the needs of your application but is not advised.